# C#/XAML Assigning Picker list ItemsSource property from a Linq Query containing strings Error: CS0029

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, casting, anonymous-types

I'm trying to use a Linq query to a local SQLite Database to assign a Picker ItemsSource property.  However, I'm getting *"{ Page_Title = Test 1 }"* instead of Test 1.
where:

**Page_Title is the column name in the SQLite Table**

**Test 1 is the value I wanted to return**

I'm assuming the reason I'm getting is because I'm using an  list instead of a string.  However, when I try to use a  list I get the following error:

*CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type "System.Collections.Generic.List anonymous type: string Page_Title" to "System.Collections.Generic.List string"*

I tried a .ConvertAll to convert the strings and it did remove the *{Page_Title = }* to return just the Test 1, but it was returned as each character as an item in the list.  Such as below:

"T"

"e"

"s"

"t"

"1"

CODE WITH Object

```
        VM_AnalyzePage CurrentPage = new VM_AnalyzePage();
                var pageList = (from UserPageTbl in conn.Table<UserPageTbl>()
                            where UserPageTbl.User_ID == App.user
                            select new
                            {
                                UserPageTbl.Page_Title

                            }).Distinct().OrderBy(Page_Title => Page_Title).ToList<object>();


            CurrentPage.PageList = pageList;
```

CODE WITH string

```
            var pageList = (from UserPageTbl in conn.Table<UserPageTbl>()
                            where UserPageTbl.User_ID == App.user
                            select new
                            {
                                UserPageTbl.Page_Title

                            }).Distinct().OrderBy(Page_Title => Page_Title).ToList();


            CurrentPage.PageList = pageList;
```

This is the class that I'm trying to set the value of.  Note, when I try to convert to a string I change "object" to "string" in the below:

```
public class VM_AnalyzePage : INotifyPropertyChanged

{

    //properties
    private List<object> pageList;


    public List<object> PageList
    {
        get
        {
            return pageList;
        }
           
        set
        {
            pageList = value;
        }
    }
```

I've also tried casting the "pageList" variable to type List string in the below, but then I get the same error:

```
            List<string> pageList = (from UserPageTbl in conn.Table<UserPageTbl>()
                            where UserPageTbl.User_ID == App.user
                            select new
                            {
                                UserPageTbl.Page_Title

                            }).Distinct().OrderBy(Page_Title => Page_Title).ToList();


            CurrentPage.PageList = pageList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome by replacing the SQL statement with the true LINQ statement:

```
                List<string> pageList = conn.Table<UserPageTbl>().Where(t => t.User_ID == App.user).Select(t=>t.Page_Title).Distinct().ToList();
```